# How can I secure this from injection and spam

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, email

I want to make my contact form less likely to suffer from an attacker.

This is what the public can see;

```
<script>
var checkobj

function agreesubmit(el){
checkobj=el
if (document.all||document.getElementById){
for (i=0;i<checkobj.form.length;i++){  //hunt down submit button
var tempobj=checkobj.form.elements[i]
if(tempobj.type.toLowerCase()=="submit")
tempobj.disabled=!checkobj.checked
}
}
}

function defaultagree(el){
if (!document.all&&!document.getElementById){
if (window.checkobj&&checkobj.checked)
return true
else{
alert("Please check the box confirming your details are correct.")
return false
}
}
}

function handleEnter (field, event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++)
                if (field == field.form.elements[i])
                    break;
            i = (i + 1) % field.form.elements.length;
            field.form.elements[i].focus();
            return false;
        } 
        else
        return true;
    }
<!--
function formCheck(formobj){
    // Enter name of mandatory fields
    var fieldRequired = Array("name", "email", "message");
    // Enter field description to appear in the dialog box
    var fieldDescription = Array("Name", "Email Address", "Your Message");
    // dialog message
    var alertMsg = "Please complete the following fields:\n";

    var l_Msg = alertMsg.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldRequired.length; i++){
        var obj = formobj.elements[fieldRequired[i]];
        if (obj){
            switch(obj.type){
            case "select-one":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == ""){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "select-multiple":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "text":
            case "textarea":
            case "password":
                if (obj.value == "" || obj.value == null){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            default:
            }
            if (obj.type == undefined){
                var blnchecked = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++){
                    if (obj[j].checked){
                        blnchecked = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!blnchecked){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(alertMsg);
        return false;
    }
}
// -->

var emailfilter=/^\w+[\+\.\w-]*@([\w-]+\.)*\w+[\w-]*\.([a-z]{2,4}|\d+)$/i

function checkmail(e){
var returnval=emailfilter.test(e.value)
if (returnval==false){
alert("Please enter a valid email address.")
e.select()
}
return returnval
}
</script>
             <div align="center">
                  <font color="#FF0000">
                  <?php
            //If there is an error message...show it.
                if(isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG'])) {
                        echo $_SESSION['ERRMSG'];
                        echo "<br>";
                    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG']);
                }
                ?>
            </font>
            </div>
      <p class="greywritingsmall" style="text-align:center">Fields marked with a <span class="purplewriting">*</span> are required. </p>
      <span style="text-align:center">
    <form action="execs/contactus.php" method="post" name="register" class="greywriting" id="register" onsubmit="return formCheck(this)">
      <table width="620" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="formgreywriting">
        <tr align="left">
          <td width="115">Full Name: <font color="#64195A">*</font></td>
          <td width="193"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_FULL_NAME'])){echo $_SESSION['SESS_FULL_NAME'];}?>" /></td>
          <td width="112">Email Address: <font color="#64195A">*</font></td>
          <td width="174"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'])){echo $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'];}?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
          <td width="115">Membership No: (If Applicable)</td>
          <td width="193"><input name="member_id" type="text" id="member_id" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event)" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'])){echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];}?>" /></td>
          <td width="112">Department: <font color="#64195A">*</font></td>
          <td width="174">
             <select name="department" id="department">
                <?php
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM departments ORDER BY name ASC");
                echo "<option value=\"\">Please select one...</option>";
                while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo "<option value=\"" . $result['code'] . "\">" . $result['name'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
             </select>
          </td>
          </tr>
        <tr align="center">
          <td colspan="1" align="left">Message: <font color="#64195A">*</font></td>
          <td colspan="3" align="left"><textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="60" id="message" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['message'])){echo $_POST['message'];}?>"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
          <img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
          <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" />

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ Different Image ]</a>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" align="center"><font color="#64195A">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tc" id="tc" onclick="agreesubmit(this)"/>
          I confirm that all my details are correct.</a></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" align="center"><input name="submit" value="Send Message" type="submit" onclick="return checkmail(this.form.email)" disabled/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <script>
    document.forms.register.tc.checked=false
    </script>
      </span></div>
```

This is the "behind the scenes" file.

```
<?php
//DB Connect
require_once('../config.php');
session_start();

// Connect to Database
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Set error flag - flase
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

//Prevent SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Colect variables
$data = array();
$data['email'] = array();
//-
$data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$data['email']['user'] = $_POST['email'];
$data['message'] = $_POST['message'];
$data['department'] = $_POST['department'];
    //Pilot ID
    if(isset($_POST['member_id'])){$data['member_id'] = $_POST['member_id'];} else {$data['member_id'] = '';}

//Checks
    //x
    //Get department email address
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM departments WHERE code = '" . $_POST['department'] . "'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $data['email']['department'] = $result['email'];
    $data['department_name'] = $result['name'];

//Any errors
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: ../index.php?p=whotocontact");
    exit();
}

//Checks
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();

//CAPTCHA
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  // the code was incorrect

  // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

  // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
  echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
  echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
  exit;
}


//Send mail
$messageunwrapped = 
"Department: $data[department_name]
Name: $data[name]
Member ID: $data[member_id]
Message:
$data[message]";
$message = wordwrap($messageunwrapped,70);
if($data['member_id'] == ''){
$subject = 'Message from ' . $data['name'];
} else {
$subject = 'Message from ' . $data['name'] . ' - ' . $data['member_id'];
}
$to = $data['email']['department'];
$headers  = 'From: '. $data['email']['user'] . "\r\n";
$sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
//Done
$errmsg = 'Success! Email Sent.';
$_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = $errmsg;
session_write_close();
header("location: ../index.php?p=whotocontact");
exit();
?>
```

I would really appreciate any help you can give me with this. Thank-you in advance.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, I am looking into "filter_var()" but not sure if this would cover it.

Comment: you need to switch to `PDO` or `MySQLi` prepared statements, I would also recommend that you use a mail library such as phpMailer [https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer] which will help prevent Mail header modifications which could be used to send spam.

Answer (score 0):

for Anti-spam you can ask the user a question like, what is `2 + 2` and `$_POST` that answer to the next page and check if the answer provided by the user equals to the answer generated by PHP.

```
$question1 = mt_rand(1,10);
$question2 = mt_rand(1,10);
$answer = $question1 + $question2;
```

in your html form create two inputs for the answer and question

```
*What is <?php echo $question1 ." + ". $question2;?>? (Anti-spam):
     <input type="number" required name="Human" ><br>
      <input name="answer" id="subject" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$answer"; ?>">
```

in your form you can check if the answer is correct

```
 <?php
     $answer = $_POST['answer'];
     if(isset ($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['human'] == answer) {
         your mail procesing here
 }
```